# ScriptResource.xsd error on site

Tags: 2010, javascript, master-page

I am getting a javascript error on all the pages in my application .
Message: 'Sys.UI' is null or not an object
Message: 'Sys.__upperCaseTypes' is null or not an object

https://site.odf.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=XXXXXXXXXXX error .

Answer (score 0):

Check web.config to have the following section completely.

```
   <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

Comment: The verb is already present in web.config file .